# I paid him money to stay in his house

Tags: meaning, verbs, time, infinitive-vs-gerund

a. I paid him money to stay in his house.

b. I paid him money for staying in his house.

Which sentence should be used if I paid him but ended up not staying in his house?

Which sentence should be used if I paid him after staying in his house?

Which should be used if I paid and then stayed in his house?

Many thanks

Comment: The nominal form in **for staying** does not unambiguously indicate that you stayed in the house since many native speakers would say that even if they had not stayed in his house yet but were planning to do so, and they might use "to stay" even if they had already stayed in his house.

Comment: Also, it kind of sounds like you really wanted him to stay home and not go out.

Comment: In (a), you paid before staying, and

In (b), you paid after staying.

Comment: @Sam  That meaning is not entailed.  A native speaker could  say to Judge Judy, "I paid him money for staying in his house but he changed his mind when I told him I had a dog and he hasn't refunded it to me yet."  Some native speakers would use "for staying" to refer to what they wished to do.

Comment: **to stay** is prospective, and for many but not all speakers, "for staying" means "for having stayed".  Some speakers could say "I paid him in advance for staying in his house."

Answer (score 3):

Neither sentence deals clearly with the examples you have outlined.

1. *I paid him money to stay in his house.* This tells us the purpose of the payment, but doesn't say whether I stayed. It doesn't even tell us when the payment was made (before, during or after the stay).
2. *I paid him money for staying in his house.* This really means the same as the other sentence. In theory "for" here could imply that the payment was made after staying. "I paid my neighbour's son for mowing my lawns" suggests the lawns are mowed in advance of payment. But we all know stories of people who pay in advance for goods or services they end up not getting.

So the real conclusion here is that if you want to make one of those cases explicit, you have to say it in the way you set out the examples in the first place. "*I paid him rent for the time that I had spent in his house*," or, "*I paid him to stay in the house but in the end I wasn't able to stay*."